# Regular expression replace but keep part of the string

Tags: java, regex

So, if I want to replace b[anything here] in a string with f[same thing here] how would I do that? Example:
What is a regular expression that would make foobarfoo to foofarfoo, and foobanfoo to foofanfoo?

Comment: i found an excellent article with tutorials here  http://www.vogella.de/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html  if you know the char you wish to replace and its location in the string this should not be too complicated from what i can see.

Comment: Is there some additional constraint you are not disclosing, or did you simply not think of replacing "b" with "f"? Properly speaking, regular expressions only match strings; replacement is not a regex feature.

Answer (score 16):

The basic principle here is a "capture group":

```
String output = input.replaceAll("foob(..)foo", "foof$1foo");
```

Put the portion of interest inside parentheses in the regular expression. It can then be referenced by its group number in [replacement text,](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String%29) or via the [`Matcher.group()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group%28int%29) method.

Comment: Thanks... Will that match a sequence of any length, or just 2 characters?

Comment: To clarify, this will turn "foobarfoo" into "foofarfoo" right?

Comment: @Tj3 I believe you'd want `"(.*)"` if you want any length. `"(..)"` will match exactly two.

Comment: @Tj3 my regex will match exactly two characters; you can modify it as needed, just keep the parentheses. I'm just trying to provide a concrete illustration based on your contrived example.

Comment: So doing: `"Hello ab hello ad".replaceAll("a([abcABC])", "b$1");` would give "Hello bb hello ad" right?