# How to make IntelliJ IDEA automatically generate a toString() format as I wish?

Tags: java

-When I use toString to print: System.out.println(animal);

- I get this : Animal{name='Shark', weight=30, speed=40}
- What I want is : Animal {name = 'Shark',
  weight = 30,
  speed = 40}.
- How I can force I-IDEA make what I want automatically?

Comment: You can override `toString()` method for `Animal` class to return whatever kind of string you want.

Comment: And i want toString generate automatically.

Comment: The only way is the one that @RohanKumar said. You can't do it automatically if you do not override toString().

Comment: It is not "Java" doing that, at least not through JDK 11 it isn't.  Maybe it's your IDE trying to "help". In any case, you have two choices: write your own ToString, or fix whatever's providing the toString for you.

Comment: The duplicate is wrong. This is not about getting Class instead of content. This is about formatting. @TuLeAnh there is no nice way to do this I can think of. 1) Override as stated but loop the properties to have it apply for different content. 2) Do a regex replace on word boundaries (\b) with space \b space. You will need capture groups for that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7630707/regular-expression-replace-but-keep-part-of-the-string

Comment: @LarsWissler I don't understand how the duplicate is wrong. The answer is simple: override `toString()`, I can reopen this question. But unless OP doesn't specify what they mean with *generate automatically* it will just get closed as unclear instead

Comment: @TuLeAnh what are you meaning exactly with generate automatically? Are you looking for something like [Lombok `@ToString`](https://projectlombok.org/features/ToString)?

Comment: @Lino Ok, I may be completely wrong, but as I understood the question it is about generic formatting. I mean the question is bad because no context about animal is provided. If it were a normal class the output would be Class@something as in the marked duplicate. Here it looks like an JSONObject or something like that and the issue is a generic output applicable to any nesting with added spaces between the seperators.

Comment: @Lino this question about formatting, i want when i create toString it will be " Animal {name = 'Shark', weight = 30, speed = 40}. " automatically, not "Animal{name='Shark', weight=30, speed=40}". And i dont want to edit when override, it must automatic.

Answer (score -1):

You can generate toString() method and edit that

Comment: actually i want it automatic

Comment: Normally it is simple with the autocompletion of Intellij. You want to have your result without override toString?