# Python - Regex - match all words between substrings and replace the substrings with other substring

Tags: python, regex

What I have:

```
s = 'Some equation goes like $T_{r}$ and here it goes the $P_{r}$. Plz remove the dollar sign'
```

What I want:

```
'Some equation goes like :math:`T_{r}` and here it goes the :math:`P_{r}`. Plz remove the dollar sign'
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regular expression replace but keep part of the string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7630707/regular-expression-replace-but-keep-part-of-the-string)

Comment: Match both the `$` signs and capture whatever inside them, then replace with `\1` wrapped in the new delimiters: [`\$([^$]*)\$`/`:math:\`\1\``](https://regex101.com/r/AcBukP/1)

Comment: @InSync it worked! thanks "re.sub('\$([^$]*)\$', r':math:`\1`', s,  flags=re.DOTALL)"

Answer (score 1):

You can use re package like this:

```py
import re

s = 'Some equation goes like $T_{r}$ and here it goes the $P_{r}$. Plz remove the dollar sign'

substring1 = "$T_{r}$"
substring2 = "$P_{r}$"

new_substring1 = ":math:`T_{r}`"
new_substring2 = ":math:`P_{r}`"

matches = re.sub(f'({re.escape(substring1)})(.*)({re.escape(substring2)})', rf'{new_substring1}\2{new_substring2}', s)
print(matches)
=> 'Some equation goes like :math:`T_{r}` and here it goes the :math:`P_{r}`. Plz remove the dollar sign'
```

We're using sub from re to replace strings using regex.

First argument we separe in three () which means 3 groups: first substring, middle content, second substring. Also need escape the substring because of special chars using `re.espace()`.

Then on second argument we say what we want replace, combining f-string and raw string literal (r) to interpolate our new_substrings and use the \2 in the middle to refer to second group on our pattern, which means the middle content.

Last argument is just the original string.